# MySql get rows where one column equals to another colum in another table where one column is equal

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have two tables:

tbl_post and tbl_public

tbl_post:

```
id | post_id   |  author  |  date (unix time)
--------------------------------
 0 |  123456   | User 1   |  1489857236
 1 |  123457   | User 2   |  1489857237
 2 |  123458   | User 3   |  1489857238
```

tbl_public:

```
    id | post_id | public | date (unix time)
    -----------------------------------------
 --> 0 |  123456 |  0     |  1489857236
     1 |  123457 |  1     |
     2 |  123458 |  0     |
 --> 3 |  123456 |  1     |  1489857239
```

i want to get all rows where user = "User 1" and the newest (order by date) public column in the table tbl_public is greater than 0 order by date DESC

Can you please help me with the query command? :)

Comment: which relatation there is between tbl_post and tbl_public ??

Comment: Hint:  `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `INNER JOIN` here is the syntax below:

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please elaborate your needs briefly, though I tried what I understand from your question. Let me know if it worked for you.

SQL:

```
SELECT
    tp.post_id,
    tp.author,
    tpb.public,
    tpb.date
FROM
    tbl_post tp
    LEFT JOIN tbl_public tpb ON (tp.post_id = tpb.post_id)
WHERE
    tp.author = 'User 1'
ORDER BY
    tpb.date DESC;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  tbl_post 'a'
  INNER JOIN tbl_public 'b' ON a.post_id = b.post_id
WHERE
  author = 'User 1'
  AND public > 0
```

Comment: i need to get column public from the newest tbl_public row (order by date desc)

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.